# How to remove charset from php curl post?

Tags: php, php-curl

Server that I am posting data to requires header that includes

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

I have a PHP code to set this header (edit)

```
    $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, $mtlsKey); // --key
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $mtlscert); // --cert
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Authorization: Bearer $token",
    "X-Req-Signature: $XReqSig",
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Content-Type: application/json"
)); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$base_url);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

- I tried to change true values to false
- tested also moving HTTPHEADER to beginning

When I check my request headers I get this

```
[content_type] => application/json;charset=utf-8
```

How do I remove charset from header? (or prevent php/server adding it?)

Comment: It might be worth seeing the remainder of the `curl` code, as what you've displayed here appears that it should work

Comment: @Martin code added

Comment: Why do you want to remove it? It's a valid header component.

Comment: @Sammitch receiving server requires the data in a specific format, request is otherwise denied